# Disable file changed checking in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I go back and forth between an IDE (intellij) and `Rstudio`. I am having issues with the latter when editing files in the former:

[image]

Actually there are many more : this is just a subset..  I was unable to find any configuration for the "check for modified files" or similar. Does it exist?

Comment: oh! nice - please make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's any way to permanently disable the messages, but you can click on the button that's supposed to say "Do not show this message again." You can also avoid it by not having unsaved changes in RStudio when you save changes from your other editor.